# Is there a simple way using CSS or Javascript to change the background color of a div based on the value of a field

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css

What I'm attempting to do is have the background of a div change from white to a very light green based on the results of a value returned from MySQL.  So I have a form that has a field called payment status, if they are paid in full I want the background color of the div to change to  light green. If payment displays no payment I want the background to display a very light red.

I did a search and attempted using this [change background color based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970902/can-i-make-a-div-change-its-background-color-based-on-the-value-inside-it)

but it's a bit too complicated for me. I was hoping I could do this with javascript or css or a combination. 
This is my line of code for the payment status `<td>Payment : </td>
    <td style="height: 30px; width: 145px;"><?php echo $data2['pay_status']?></td>`

so based on the value of pay_status is what I want to use to change the background color.

*******UPDATE********
So after a lot of trial and error I've come up with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nG3VF/2/)
This works like a charm if I needed to change the background color of an input box but I need to change the div background color? can someone help me modify this to change the div instead of the input box?

Comment: "returned" via Ajax, or a page load?

Comment: @McGarnagle I'm not quite sure what you are asking, if you are asking if the value is returned via Ajax or page load it's a page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out using javascript here is the  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nG3VF/13/)
Thanks to everybody that gave suggestions!

```
var div = document.getElementById('info');
var payment = document.getElementById('paystatus');
var green = "#66ff99";
var red = "#ff9999";
if (payment.value == 'Paid in Full') {
div.style.backgroundColor = green;
} else {
div.style.backgroundColor = red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a PHP bool variable `paidInFull`, it should be straightforward to transfer that to a color on the page.  For example:

```
<?php 
    $paidinFull = $mysqlresult['paymentStatus'] == 'paidinfull';
?>

<div style='background-color: <?php echo $paidInFull ? "#aaaaff" : "#ffaaaa"; ?>'>
    Payment status
</div>
```

Comment: You learn something every day. Didn't know you could use conditional op in that way with php

Comment: @McGarnale Sorry I'm confused, I'm still learning php so I'm not sure where I need to add this or if it will work as I don't have a bool variable $painInFull. I have a drop down box that the values are selected from then submitted to MySQL on the returned results based on the value in the payment status field I was hoping to be able to use some JS to say if value is this then change bg color of div to this?

Comment: @user2447848 You don't necessarily need JS -- easier to set the color directly if the server knows what it should be.  You should be able to set up a `paidInFull` based on the MySQL result field, as above, no?

Comment: @McGarnagle thanks I'll give your edit a try and see what happens

Comment: @McGarnagle I must be doing something wrong as it turns the page red regardless of the value. I think I'll just leave it as it is with the white background. I'm getting in over my head with my current knowledge of php and what's needed to be done to achieve this. But thanks for your help it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set a php variable to be what is returned from fronts database and have that as the class of the containing element. You'll need a couple of classes in your CSS.

Using phone and hard to write code on it but you can either use php to echo to value into the class value of the parent HTML element or run an if else and display the div depending on outcome

...

Forgot {} in the above buy this will work

Comment: I assumed you're using php.

Comment: Yes php is being used.

Comment: <?php if(phpVariableFromSql = meh) ?>
<div class="mehRed">...
<?php else if (phpVariableFromSql = bla) ?>
<div class ="blaBlue">

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you're looking for. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QYMJT/) is a jsfiddle with everything working. It's all javascript. Basically, based on the response from your server, you just highlight it green if it's paid and leave it white otherwise. Here's the javascript snippet:

// call this function after you've gotten your answer from your server
    $('.payment').each(function () {
    //first you see what's inside the div
   var wordsInsideDiv = $(this).html(); 
    if(wordsInsideDiv.indexOf('not') != -1) {
         $(this).css('background-color', 'white');

```
}
else{
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
}
});
```

and the html I used:

```
the guy hasn't paid
<div class="payment">
    paid status: not paid
</div>

the guy paid
<div class="payment">
    paid status: totally paid
</div>
```

Notice that i'm simply using the word "not" to trigger whether or not I highlight it green. So whatever the actual value of your response from the database shoudl determine your if statement in the javascript.

cheers!

Comment: I tried this but can't get it to work and I don't see it working in the jsfiddle either. I added the class="payment" tag to the div and changed the word from not to Paid in Full as to what the script is looking for in the div but no dice, doesn't change color.

Comment: correction I changed the word from not to No Payment but still no change. is there a way to check just the value of the pay_status field and make the color change based on that value?

Comment: I'm confused, did you modify the javascript as well? The javascript is looking for the word "not" so if you changed it to "no" then you should modify the javascript as well

Comment: I only modified the javascript to the words No Payment as that is what would reflect in my MySQL results, either No Payment or Paid in Full. I still haven't been able to get it to work in the jsfiddle either, just shows two white boxes.